# Inconvenient upgrading files to remote repository on git

Tags: php, git, version-control, github, centos

In my work I've a git repository for a project in a VPS, and I cloned it on differents machines of my team locally... When one of us makes a change in one of the files of the project from his computer, type ** git add .** then **git commit -m "Commit"** and later the **git push origin master**... If I go with ssh to the VPS and see the **git log** in the repository, perfectly see the last commit added... But when I go to the vim to see the changes on the file THERE ARE NO CHANGES ON IT =( and I've to make a **git reset --hard "commit-number"** to apply changes... For example, if I type the **git log** in the remote repository I see this:

commit a00437828e403bef3ba90025d04cb1ebd5d1e671

Author: appuser

Date:   Thu Aug 22 14:33:08 2013 -0430

```
Se arega comentario a prueba4.php desde repositorio de appuser
```

commit 3c153f57eca69c78b83309237bc9f40753ea9909

Author: Usuario Repositorio Central Mediación

Date:   Thu Aug 22 14:29:16 2013 -0430

```
Cambio sobre archivo prueba4.php para ver el nuevo nombre en mediacion
```

commit 8682aabecfcb9b094ad7abaa41b08924e0bc88f0

Author: Daniel Eduardo Delgado Diaz

Date:   Thu Aug 22 14:25:32 2013 -0430

```
Se cambió nuevamente archivo prueba4.php desde equipo local Daniel
```

I see the last commit that puts the author appuser saying that he makes changes on the file prueba4.php with when i open the file there are no changes. What the hell I'm doing wrong?? =(

Pd
Sorry for my bad english!!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be missing the steps:

```
git pull
git update
```

Comment: Plus this: Usually the central remote repository is set up as a `bare` repository without checked out files. If you want checked out files, you can do so by extending git using hooks and triggers.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever do a **git pull** from the remote repository?

Answer (score 0):

There is not much done wrong, the misunderstanding is that `git push` does not update the checked out files of the remote repository, it updates the git image of files, which resides somewhere in the .git directory.

This is why you would create a central repository as a "bare" repository e.g. with `git clone --bare XXX`

If you want the central repository to be automatically checked out and updates, you can use hooks and triggers, examples of which are located somewhere below the .git directory. See http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks